# Inserting in sceneGroup pushes to background?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have no idea how to describe this problem in the title, sorry.

```
local bBbackground = display.newRoundedRect( Backgroundrectangle.x+(Backgroundrectangle.width/4), Backgroundrectangle.y, 100, 125, 10 )
sceneGroup:insert(bBbackground)
bBbackground.id = "b"
bBbackground.strokeWidth = 2
bBbackground:setFillColor( gradient )
bBbackground:setStrokeColor( 0.2 )

bBmenutext = display.newText( "Bb", 100, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 50)
bBmenutext.x = bBbackground.x
bBmenutext.y = bBbackground.y - aAbackground.height/6
bBmenutext:setFillColor( 0.2 )
bBscoretext = display.newText( "4/8", 100, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 30)
bBscoretext.x = bBbackground.x 
bBscoretext.y = bBbackground.y + bBbackground.height/4
bBscoretext:setFillColor( 0.7 )
sceneGroup:insert(bBmenutext)
sceneGroup:insert(bBscoretext)
```

If I take out the sceneGroup:insert then everything is how I want it: bBmenutext and bBscoretext appear in front of the bBbackground. However, as it is, the text groups are behind it. I have also tried adding:

```
bBbackground:toBack()
bBmenutext:toFront()
bBscoretext:toFront()
```

but to no avail. Any solution please? I have quite new to Corona and really by greatest frustration has been trying to make sure everything is removed at the end of the scene. I really need to figure out how to get things into that group without completely messing up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code is [scene template](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) to check. It works as expected

test.lua

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()


-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Scene event functions
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- create()
    function scene:create( event )

        local sceneGroup = self.view
        local bBbackground = display.newRoundedRect( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 100, 125, 10 )
        sceneGroup:insert(bBbackground)
        bBbackground.id = "b"
        bBbackground.strokeWidth = 2
        bBbackground:setFillColor( gradient )
        bBbackground:setStrokeColor( 0.2 )

        bBmenutext = display.newText( "Bb", 100, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 50)
        bBmenutext.x = bBbackground.x
        bBmenutext.y = bBbackground.y - 30
        bBmenutext:setFillColor( 0.2 )
        bBscoretext = display.newText( "4/8", 100, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 30)
        bBscoretext.x = bBbackground.x 
        bBscoretext.y = bBbackground.y + bBbackground.height/4
        bBscoretext:setFillColor( 0.7 )
        sceneGroup:insert(bBmenutext)
        sceneGroup:insert(bBscoretext)

    end


    -- show()
    function scene:show( event )

        local sceneGroup = self.view
        local phase = event.phase

        if ( phase == "will" ) then
            -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

        elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
            -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
    physics.start()
        end
    end


    -- hide()
    function scene:hide( event )

        local sceneGroup = self.view
        local phase = event.phase

        if ( phase == "will" ) then
            -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)

        elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
            -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen

        end
    end


    -- destroy()
    function scene:destroy( event )

        local sceneGroup = self.view
        -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view

    end


    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Scene event function listeners
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return scene
```

main.lua

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

composer.gotoScene(  'test' )
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you. bBbackground was already in a group so removing it from the previous group fixed it.